# Get properties from derived class in base class

Tags: c#, oop, reflection

How do I get properties from derived class in base class?

Base class:

```
public abstract class BaseModel {
    protected static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<BaseModel, object>>
            _propertyGetters = typeof(BaseModel).GetProperties().Where(p => _getValidations(p).Length != 0).ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => _getValueGetter(p));
}
```

Derived classes:

```
public class ServerItem : BaseModel, IDataErrorInfo {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field name is required.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OtherServerItem : BaseModel, IDataErrorInfo {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field name is required.")]
    public string OtherName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Field SomethingThatIsOnlyHereis required.")]
    public string SomethingThatIsOnlyHere{ get; set; }
}
```

In this example - can I get the "Name" property from ServerItem class while in BaseModel class?

EDIT:
I'm trying to implement model validation, as described here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2009/04/17/wpf-validation-with-attributes-and-idataerrorinfo-interface-in-mvvm.aspx

I figured that if I create some base model with (almost) all of the validation magic in it, and then extend that model, it will be okay...

Comment: Well you're *explicitly* asking for the properties of `BaseModel`. It's really unclear what you're trying to do, or what you'd expect to happen if you had other derived classes.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  It is probably solvable with conventional technique, 
using reflection to bend your code like that is generally very bad and points to a design problem.

Comment: Multiple inheritance !!! as i was taught in university, c# doesn't allow it... ?

Comment: No, BaseModel doesn't know about ServerItem, unless it is a ServerItem.

Comment: @Shaharyar multiple inheritance is allowed when it comes to interfaces

Comment: @nienawiedzony Got it !! :)

Comment: So what happens if two derived classes introduce unrelated properties with different types but with the same name?

Comment: Good question - probably something bad, but let's not think about that ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If both classes are in the same assembly, you can try this:

```
Assembly
    .GetAssembly(typeof(BaseClass))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass))
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetProperties());
```

This will give you all the properties of all the subclasses of `BaseClass`.

Answer (score 8):

If you require that a derived class *must* implement a method or property, you should introduce that method or property into the base class as an abstract declaration.

For example, for your `Name` property, you would add to the base class:

```
public abstract string Name { get; set; }
```

Then any derived classes *must* implement it, or be abstract classes themselves.

Once you have added the abstract version of the `Name` property to the base class, you will be able to access it in the base class anywhere *except* in the base class's constructor.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to throw every property from my derived models into the base class - it has no sense :)

Comment: To add an abstract property to a base class, the base class itself must be abstract.

Comment: @SteveD Indeed - and the base class is abstract. See the OP for details.

Answer (score 7):

If you **must** do literally fetch property of derived class from within base class, you can use Reflection, for example - like this...

```
using System;
public class BaseModel
{
    public string getName()
    {
        return (string) this.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(this, null);
    }
}

public class SubModel : BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SubModel b = new SubModel();
            b.Name = "hello";
            System.Console.Out.WriteLine(b.getName()); //prints hello
        }
    }
}
```

This is not recommended, though, and you most probably should rethink your design like Matthew said.

As for not throwing properties to your base classes -- you can try to decouple base and deriving classes into unrelated objects and pass them via constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve this issue by create **virtual** property in base class and **override** it to derived class.

```
public class Employee
{
    public virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

public class GeneralStaff
{
    public override string Name {get; set;}
}

class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Employee emp = new GeneralStaff();
            emp.Name = "Abc Xyz";
            //---- More code follows----            
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved this problem slightly different than the author of this post: http://weblogs.asp.net/marianor/archive/2009/04/17/wpf-validation-with-attributes-and-idataerrorinfo-interface-in-mvvm.aspx

```
public abstract class BaseModel : IDataErrorInfo {
    protected Type _type;
    protected readonly Dictionary<string, ValidationAttribute[]> _validators;
    protected readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> _properties;

    public BaseModel() {
        _type = this.GetType();
        _properties = _type.GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p);
        _validators = _properties.Where(p => _getValidations(p.Value).Length != 0).ToDictionary(p => p.Value.Name, p => _getValidations(p.Value));
    }

    protected ValidationAttribute[] _getValidations(PropertyInfo property) {
        return (ValidationAttribute[])property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ValidationAttribute), true);
    }

    public string this[string columnName] {
        get {
            if (_properties.ContainsKey(columnName)) {
                var value = _properties[columnName].GetValue(this, null);
                var errors = _validators[columnName].Where(v => !v.IsValid(value)).Select(v => v.ErrorMessage).ToArray();
                return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors);
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public string Error {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
}
```

Maybe it will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Scan your assembly for all inherited classes from BaseModel and create dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, Func<BaseModel, object>>>
```

Comment: Can't do it - you can't use this keyword outside of methods or properties

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution that would let me avoid this. Still - creative thinking ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TESTNEW
{
   public abstract class BusinessStructure
    {
       public BusinessStructure()
       { }

       public string Name { get; set; }
   public string[] PropertyNames{
       get
       { 
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] Pr;
                System.Type _type = this.GetType();
                Pr = _type.GetProperties();
                string[] ReturnValue = new string[Pr.Length];
                for (int a = 0; a <= Pr.Length - 1; a++)
                {
                    ReturnValue[a] = Pr[a].Name;
                }
                return ReturnValue;
       }
   }

}


public class MyCLS : BusinessStructure
   {
       public MyCLS() { }
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string Value { get; set; }


   }
   public class Test
   {
       void Test()
       {
           MyCLS Cls = new MyCLS();
           string[] s = Cls.PropertyNames;
           for (int a = 0; a <= s.Length - 1; a++)
           {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(s[a].ToString());
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using code-only answers. Try adding some text describing what this code does, and how it will solve the asker's question.