# how can I get subclass properties and set the value?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I m trying to get all properties from a sub class and then set the value.
but I dont not know how I can start. I know how I can get the properties and set the value. but no on a sub class.

```
public class Program {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {

    object[] Response = new object[] {
      new Cars() {
        Details = new Details() {
          CanDrive = true,
          ID = 123,
          IsPolice = true
        },
        Name = "test",
        Speed = 100
      }
    };

    var Result = Test <Cars> (Response);
    Console.WriteLine(Result.Speed);

  }
  private static T Test <T> (object[] Obj) {
    var Instance = CreateInstance <T> ();

    foreach(var Ob in Obj) {

      PropertyInfo[] C = Ob.GetType().GetProperties();
      foreach(var n in C) {

        PropertyInfo[] P = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach(PropertyInfo Val in P) {
          if (n.Name == Val.Name) V
              Val.SetValue(Instance, n.GetValue(Ob));
        }
      }
    }

    return Instance;
  }
  private static T CreateInstance <T>() => Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
  public class Cars {
    public int Speed { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Details Details { get; set; }
  }
  public class Details {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool CanDrive { get; set;}
    public bool IsPolice { get; set; }
  }
}
```

how can I get the sub classes? and set the value of the class?

**Edit**
Updated my Code. for better understanding.

Comment: You call `CreateInstance<Cars>`, which will create an instance of the class `Cars`. It doesn't look like you have an instance of the subclass, `Details`.

Comment: well. that could be easy done. but how can I get the properties of the sub class?

Comment: Is it something similar to this is what you're looking at? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834403/get-properties-from-derived-class-in-base-class

Comment: If you want to get the properties of `Details`, then use `typeof(Details)` instead of `typeof(Cars)`. Are you sure you need to be doing this with reflection, though? Can you just have an instance of `Details` and call its properties like `detailInstance.ID = 1234`?

Comment: If there is be an inner class then `Cars` ought to instantiate it as part of its own intialization.  But as presented, there is no compelling reason for `Details` since those are all `Car` properties and not some other logical part such as the transmission or  power train description

Comment: @JoeSewell Updated the Code.

Comment: are you simply attempting to take an Array of objects and make it an array of cars?

Comment: @LukeHammer noo this should be a auto parser the same as Newton.Json does. I only want to know how can I get the properties from the sub class the same as `PropertyInfo[] P = typeof(T).GetProperties();`

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why we're going all the way up to reflection for this?

Could this just be as simple as

```
 var car = new Car();
        car.Details = new Details()
        {
            CanDrive = true,
            ID = 42,
            IsPolice = false
        };
```

Comment: no. I m getting a object response with different types. this should be a parser the same as Newton.Json does. everything works. I only want to know how to get the sub class properties

Comment: Can we just access the same way you do car?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var CarInstance = CreateInstance<Cars>();

        PropertyInfo[] P = typeof(Cars).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo Car in P)
        {
              if(Car.Details.IsPolice) //Access properties of subclass using the name of the property, which is "Details"
                  Car.SetValue(CarInstance, 12345);
            
               if(Car.Name == "ID") 
                  Car.SetValue(CarInstance, 12345);
            
        }
    }
    private static T CreateInstance<T>() => Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    public class Cars
    {
        public int Speed { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Details Details { get; set; }
    }
    public class Details
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public bool CanDrive { get; set; }
        public bool IsPolice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This minor difference may help clear up some confusion:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        var CarInstance = CreateInstance<Cars>();

        PropertyInfo[] P = typeof(Cars).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo Car in P)
        {
              if(Car.ThisCarDetails.IsPolice) //Access properties of subclass using the name of the property, which is "ThisCarDetails"
                  Car.SetValue(CarInstance, 12345);
            
               if(Car.Name == "ID") 
                  Car.SetValue(CarInstance, 12345);
            
        }
    }
    private static T CreateInstance<T>() => Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    public class Cars
    {
        public int Speed { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Details ThisCarDetails { get; set; }
    }
    public class Details
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public bool CanDrive { get; set; }
        public bool IsPolice { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what it the difference?

Comment: The difference is the name of the property. In the first snippet, the name is "Details". In the second snippet, it's "ThisCarDetails". Same behavior, but it illustrates how you access properties of a subclass using the names of the properties of the parent class.